# Falha ao converter o valor da propriedade do tipo 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Galera é o seguinte, estou tentando submeter um formulário que em uma das classes existe um relacionamento, gostaria de saber como devo fazer isto, pois toda vez que tento submeter recebo o erro de "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String'"

Segue abaixo meu model

```
@Entity
public class Musica{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Campo está vazio ou nulo.")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "titulo", length = 50)
    private String titulo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoMusica generoMusica;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_playlist_fk")
        private Playlist playlist;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_artista_fk")
        private Artista artista;
```

Meu formulario na view:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/musicas/Adicionar-Musica" th:object="${musica}" method="post">
   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 offset-md-4">
     <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('titulo')}">
      <label class="validation-message" th:errors="*{titulo}"></label>
     </div>
      <label class="lbl">Nome da Música</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{titulo}" placeholder="Ex: Por baixo ou Por Cima de Mim..">
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-4 offset-md-4">
     <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('artista')}">
      <label class="validation-message" th:errors="*{artista}"></label>
     </div>
      <label class="lbl" >Artista/Banda</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{artista}" placeholder="Ex: Henrique e Juliano">
    </div>
   </div>
    
<a class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mt-2" href="/"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;VOLTAR</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;SALVAR INFORMAÇÕES</button>    
   </form>
```

Por fim meu controller:

```
@PostMapping("/Adicionar-Musica")
public ModelAndView inserirMusica(@Valid Musica musica, BindingResult br) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    if(br.hasErrors()) {
        mv.setViewName("musicas/adicionar-musica");
        mv.addObject("musica");
    }else {
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/musicas/lista-musicas");
        repositoriomusica.save(musica);
    }
    return mv;

}
```

O erro que me aparece ao tentar salvar as informações:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type br.com.neo.springmusic.model.Artista for property artista; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type br.com.neo.springmusic.model.Artista for property artista: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para salvar um artista sem receber o erro de conversão?

Comment: Posta o StackTrace do erro, pf.

Comment: pronto coloquei o retorno que aparece ao tentar salvar

Answer (score 0):

O erro está lhe dizendo que não pode converter uma string pra um objeto complexo do tipo artista.

No seu formulário vc deveria estar passando algo como `artista.nome` imagino.

Verifique se assim o objeto será instanciado corretamente na submissão.

Answer (score 0):

Galera eu consegui resolver o problema! fiz algumas modificações na medida que iria corrigindo os erros que vinham aparecendo. Mas gostaria de agradecer pela dica "artista.nome". Isto resolveu porém recebi outro erro pois não tinha criado os getters e setters da classe mas consegui resolver e submeter o formulário. agradeço e fica como dica para quem apresentar este mesmo problema.